# Javascript code not functioning correctly in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have been fighting with this for a couple of days now. I can't see why this wouldn't work in Chrome, but does work in IE.

The required drop-down box I want to appear doesn't, and it also does not write to the console screen. Any help would be great.

Thanks

```
    function showYear() {
        var typeReq = document.getElementById("Formtype");
        var aYear = document.getElementById("year");
        if (typeReq.value == "Upload") {
            console.log('upload selected');
            aYear.style.visibility ="visible";
        } else {
            console.log('View selected');
            loadUpload()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML as well? Preferably on http://JSFiddle.net

Comment: With this code, I suppose no one can see why. Try cooking up a jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer's implementation of `getElementById` will return an element with the `name` attribute if it matches the parameter of the function.  Make sure you use the `id` attribute in your HTML:

```
<!-- wrong -->
<input name="Formtype" />

<!-- right -->
<input id="FormType" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem correctly, you must be calling the function `showYear();` before the DOM ready.

try calling the function once the DOM is ready.

Comment: hi, yes the function is being called when a user selects one of two options from a drop down box